# How to upgrade serenity and its dependencies in my bdd framework

Tags: selenium, maven, serenity-bdd, cucumber-junit, cucumber-serenity

I have a serenity bdd automation framework using maven, junit selenium, cucumber and serenity. My current serenity core version is 1.5.3. I am trying to upgrade it to the latest version of serenity core. Once i update the version and dependencies for the same in pom.xml, the framework stops executing the tests all together. Can someone help me in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of serenity which is `2.4.25`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.25</version>
</dependency>
```

You need to have have inline latest version of selenium and Junit.

get latest dependency from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/)